# How can I tell why Meteor autorun is triggered

Tags: javascript, meteor

I found my `Tracker.autorun` runs multiple times, and I don't know why, is there a way to find out which reactive computation triggered the `autorun`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Tracker.autorun(function(comp) {
  comp.onInvalidate(function() {
    console.trace();
  });

  // autorun code here
});
```